# sending data via ajax to controller is always null

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller, fullcalendar

I'm trying to create a function for adding events in my asp.net core MVC app via ajax:

View.cshtml:

```
function Add() {
            var eventdto = {};
            eventdto.id = "F51B27EE-27F6-4C50-BD81-08DBF0494506";
            eventdto.Title = $('#Title').val();
            eventdto.Description = $('#Description').val();
            eventdto.Start = $('#Start').val();
            eventdto.End = $('#End').val();
            eventdto.AllDay = $('#AllDay').val();
            eventdto.Url = $('#Url').val();
            eventdto.BackgroundColor = $('#BackgroundColor').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/JsonTest",
                data: '{eventdto: ' + JSON.stringify(eventdto) + '}',
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#schedule').modal('hide');
                },
                error: function (errormessage) {
                    alert(errormessage.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
```

Controller.cs:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult JsonTest(EventDTO eventdto)
        {
           return Json(eventdto);
        }
```

and in view eventdto generated successfully:
[eventdto in view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRmYm.png)

but in my controller eventdto is always null:
[eventdto in controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQlmm.png)

i trying sending data like:

`data: eventdto,`

`data: {eventdto},`

`data: {eventdto: eventdto},`

```
data: { eventdto:
                         {
                            "title" : "asdasd",
                            description : "asdasd",
                            start : "asdasd",
                            end : "asdasd",
                            allDay : "asdasd",
                            url : "asdasd",
                            backgroundColor : "asdasd"
                    }
                },
```

I have tried various solutions I found on the web ([FormBody], change name of eventdo property to "data" and some others), but value is always null. what im doing wrong?

Comment: can you see the data being sent in the request (browser *developer* tools will let you see) - if so, then the issue is the server

Comment: ohm wait `'{eventdto: ' + JSON.stringify(eventdto) + '}'` that's ugly - exactly what JSON is the server expecting ... exactly - at a guess, you want `data: JSON.stringify(eventdto)`

Comment: yes i tried this way too `data: JSON.stringify(eventdto)`, but still all is null

Comment: and the eventdto:
`var eventdto =`
                `{`
                   `title: $('#Title').val(),`
                   `description: $('#Description').val(),`
                   `start: $('#Start').val(),`
                   `end: $('#End').val(),`
                   `allDay: $('#AllDay').val(),`
                   `url: $('#Url').val(),`
                   `backgroundColor: $('#BackgroundColor').val()`
                `};`

Comment: must be the server code that's wrong then - have you checked the browser *developer* tools to see what your code is sending

Comment: it is? 
https://ibb.co/VSN073K

but my event model contains this properties: 
    `public Guid Id { get; set; }`
    `public string Title { get; set; } = null!;`
    `public DateTime Start { get; set; }`
    `public DateTime End { get; set; }`
    `public string? Description { get; set; }`
    `public bool AllDay { get; set; }`
    `public string? Url { get; set; }`
    `public string? BackgroundColor { get; set; }`

if i send null Id or allDay as string parameter, can my problem caused by this?

Comment: so .. have ... you ... checked ... what ... the ... browser ... is ... actually ... sending ...

Comment: yes i send the picture in last comment 
ibb.co/VSN073K,
and i tryed send all properties with right parameters, still empty sending

Comment: OK, so, it's the server that has the issue then

Comment: i added attribute [FromBody] to JsonTest method in controller, and when i send right data (with right parameters, like allday is true or false), its work. Earlier it is not working because sending parameter "allday" was string. Thank you for the help!!!